# Elastic APM Node.js - Don't monitor HTTP, custom transactions only

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm looking to use Elastic APM to monitor my own custom events only (user action events) in Node.js

I can't find in the docs how to turn off all HTTP monitoring and also how to send a custom event. They have custom span and custom transaction in the docs but I'm not sure when or how to use either for my use case.

For example in the docs they describe a custom transaction as follows:

```
var apm = require('elastic-apm-node').start()

queue.on('error', function (err) {
  // in case the queue encounters an error, report it to Elastic APM
  apm.captureError(err)
})
```

I'm not looking to send an error, I'm looking to send a custom event so I'm not sure what's up with that.

Comment: Please check the following example which should be pretty clear: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/nodejs/current/custom-transactions.html

Comment: @Val what about turning off HTTP monitoring?

Comment: also not clear if I should use a span or transaction